# How can I get awx to use azure_rm.yml instead of the ini version?

Tags: ansible-inventory, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I need to use the "plugin/azure_rm.yml" version of azure_rm instead of the older/deprecated "script/azure_rm.ini" to gather dynamic inventory in Azure, in particular because we need VMs from scalesets to be included in inventory.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inventory script, which (again) calls ansible-inventory, and have it create the config file via a `heredoc`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat > azure_rm.yml <<HEREDOC
---
plugin: azure_rm
include_vmss_resource_groups:
- '*'
hostvar_expressions:
  ansible_host: private_ipv4_addresses | first
plain_host_names: true
keyed_groups:
# places each host in a group named 'tag_(tag name)_(tag value)' for each tag on a VM.
- prefix: tag
  key: tags
# places each host in a group named 'azure_loc_(location name)', depending on the VM's location
- prefix: azure_loc
  key: location
# group by platform (to copy prefix from ec2.py), eg: platform_windows
- prefix: platform
  key: os_disk.operating_system_type
HEREDOC
ansible-inventory -i azure_rm.yml --list
rm azure_rm.yml
```

So it's literally having ansible-inventory call ansible-inventory, but with a different argument.  Note that in order to get the inventory for the correct subscription, you have to create a copy the credential used, with the desired subscription id; it doesn't appear that you can override AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID via the yml environment param.